# Inclusion and Exclusion of Model Properties in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, models, inclusion

I have a user model and there are different properties I want to be obtainable in different circumstances,

I have a WebAPI that handles the User Model, and for different actions, I need certain properties excluded.

E.g.

When I do /API/Users -> I want to omit the passwords as this will enable someone to see the hashes of all the passwords.

However I can't outright omit the passwords as the password is required by actions such as login.

What is the best solution to enable omission of certain fields depending on the circumstances?

As a work around I added this code to my API Action

```
       // GET: api/Users
        public List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return db.Users.ToList().Select(u => { u.password = ""; return u; }).ToList();

        }
```

but surely there is a more elegant solution than this. Ideally I would like to add an annotation to the action that precludes certain properties from the result set

Comment: This is very vague. It's hard to tell where exactly you need help. it could be as basic as knowing how to do projections, who knows?

Comment: I remember in one of my jobs we used includable and excludable annotations but I'm not sure what framework that was, do you know what framework they are used in?

Comment: What's the content result for the user? XML? JSON?